# How to avoid showing in-app review prompt to user if user has already rated an application

Tags: ios, storekit

I'm using SKStoreReviewController.requestReview() API provided by Apple to show prompt to user to rate my application. But I don't want to show prompt to user if he/she has already rated my application. How can I do it. Is it automatically handled by SKStoreReviewController If NOT, how can it do it? If YES, how can I verify it in dev environment?

I'm not able to find any Apple doc regarding it.

Comment: Did you read the documentation for `SKStoreReviewController requestReview`? It basically answers your question (mostly).

Comment: Hi @rmaddy,

It answered some part of my question. Mainly i want to know the behavior of requestReview() API in live app. 

Apple Doc: "When you call this method in your shipping app and a rating/review request view is displayed, the system handles the entire process for you."

It is not mentioned that if user has already rated an application then will he/she be prompted again if i call this API again. (say after 1 month)

Comment: @VarunMehta You are right, the documentation is not very specific. The truth is that this is a black box. In a live app you can requestReview and it is not guaranteed that the pop up will show up even after 1 month. If the user has already rated or not it might be shown or not. But it will be decided by the black box.

Comment: @VarunMehta Did you find an answer for that?

Comment: @dor506 No, i didn't get any answer for it at that time. I had to write my own logic to avoid calling requestReview() after some time.

Answer (score 12):

Late response to the OP but hopefully this is helpful to others.

Apple did not make the answer easy to find but it does say [here](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/system-capabilities/ratings-and-reviews/) that the review request dialog will not be shown if a user has already given feedback.

> If the user hasn't already given feedback, the system displays an
> in-app prompt that asks for a rating and an optional written review

Therefore, the `SKStoreReviewController.requestReview()` API will take care of the logic that makes sure the in-app review request dialog is not shown if the user has already written a review for your app on the users current version. When the app's bundle version is updated on the user device, it may show the dialog as long as you have not surpassed Apple's quota (can only display the in-app review request dialog 3 times in a year)